# How to convert kivy app to apk using p4a-build?

Tags: kivy, p4a

I have a full functional android app. I can run it on android phone using kivy launcher. Now, i want to convert it to apk. I read lot of tutorials but since i am on windows, this task seems impossible.

I read about p4a-build and followed this code

```
pip install --upgrade p4a-build
p4a-build --package com.test.helloworld --name 'Hello world' --version '1.0' \
  --modules 'kivy' --dir /path/to/helloworld
```

install was successful , but 2nd command gives error that p4a-build is not recognized. Any idea, how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this tool is really maintained, it might not work anyway. I guess your problem is that the pip package doesn't put the binary somewhere on your PATH though, if you can work out where pip packages are installed you can look for the p4a-build executable.

A more reliable solution that should certainly work is to build your apks within a linux virtual machine.

Comment: Do you know a link, where it is explained clearly to use linux virtual machine. I downloaded an image of buildozer and started vm, it just shows a black screen and i am not able to type anything.